Cut way into the spigot threads while cutting off a hose fitting, any hope of fixing it without replacing the whole thing?
First time cutting an absurdly stuck pipe fitting and I managed to do an impressively bad job. I cut into the spigot in two places, including on the surface that should seal to the pipe (picture in link below). Is there any hope of rescuing this with caulk, pipe dope, etc., or does the spigot just need to be replaced?



Would love to avoid a large plumber's bill, but also that's how I got into this mess and I'm not messing around with it further, if the spigot needs replacing I'll have the professionals do it since the housing is cracked and it's hard to access. Thanks!

Replacement is the only option.  The good news is it looks threaded on, so two wenches(pipe type) might be all that is required.  If the two first wenches do not turn it, get bigger wenches or pipes(steel) that fit over the handles.  A picture below the surface will help.

Thank you! Would a M to F coupling salvage it so the spigot side could be sealed with teflon tape/pipe dope and the water line end could seal with a flat surface, or is that a lost cause? I can't get a picture below the surface since it's kind of in the wall as the plastic is broken, which complicates switching it out.

Can try anything you want.  Some will last a few minutes to maybe a day.  A two part epoxy weld adhesive might last some time, but doing it right will take some work(more than replacement usually).  Will need a spacer pipe inside the hole and a hose threaded on to match the threads.  Do not even think of removing that hose ever.

Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it!

that's how I got into this mess  ... looks like you got into this mess by not considering what your actions are causing ... chalk it up to experience

A person might be able to braze some material on there and file it down to rebuild the threads and mating surface.  But given your previous butchery, I'm not sanguine about your brazing or filing skills.
